# JSON Query in Google Sheets/Scripts

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am importing data from a JSON file using Google Apps Script and Google Sheets. I have learned the basics on this, but the formatting on the [JSON file I am attempting to parse](https://eddb.io/archive/v5/commodities.json) is throwing me off.

What is confusing me is how I would search for information based on "name". Currently I am using this:

```
function JSONReq(url, xpath){
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var content = res.getContentText();
  var json = JSON.parse(content);

  var patharray = xpath.split("/");

  for(var i = 0; i < patharray.length; i++){
    json = json[patharray[i]];
  }

  return json;
}
```

I'm a bit lost now to be honest with you.
I want to have a cell where I can type a name that I already know of, then find it in the JSON file and pull the return that information however I decide to do it. I can pull and write to cells, I have the basics down. But I just can't understand how I could search by the name.

Comment: One issue is that you overwrite the json object in your for loop, so only the final element will be returned. How are you calling this `JSONReq` function?

Comment: For testing I am just entering =JASONReq("https://eddb.io/archive/v5/commodities.json","name") into a cell and getting nothing back. But what I want eventually is to run it multiple times for multiple JSON files and run some tests and comparisons. What I want here is if I enter "Explosives" into a cell i want to get the average_price of Explosives. I will run it off a button running another function that will call this one multiple times.

Comment: For that input, `json = json["name"]` returns nothing because is `json["name"] is undefined (`JSON.parse` is returning an array that has only numeric indices). See my answer for how to check what is present

Answer (score 0):

That JSON file is an array of objects. To find a specific object with a given `"name"`, you would parse it into an object (which you do already), then iterate through them and check the name parameter:

```
var myName = "name of thing I want";
var arr = JSON.parse( ... );
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    var obj = arr[i];
    if(obj.name == myName) { // could be done as obj["name"] == ... too
        // do stuff with obj
    }
}
```

For your case, you might add an additional argument to your function (i.e. 2nd arg = the object's property, e.g. `"name"`, with the 3rd = the desired value. This will be fine for any simple key-value properties, but would need specific handling for where the value is itself an object (e.g. the "category" field in your specific JSON file).